# Creating a Windows Gadget that gets populated from a Sharepoint List

Tags: 2010, 2007, list, development, custom

I am trying to create a Windows Gadget for a Intranet site with hundred of sites & different groups with different permissions.

The intranet site is secured with SSL/https, I looked at google gadgets & Windows Gadget to integrate them to current scenario, but google gadgets not seems to be working over SSL, anyway my real question is,

**I find this gmail gadget, which works properly and using .Net c# for most of its operations, I was wondering how can I convert it to get Items from a sharepoint list.**

whether I use webservices then how, or use Sharepoint object model and create a dll, and use it in the project, but am still confused if it gonna work over SSL.

here's the project Link (it is using java script to load windows library so its defiantly something good to investigate into, + I am planning to put this gadget on CodePlex and help other people, so please contribute)

[Gmail Gadet Windows 7](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17408/NET-Interop-for-Gadgets-A-C-GMail-Inbox-Reader-Ex)

I find this gadget as well, but it doesn't work for me, dunno why tho,

[Sharepoint List Gadget](http://datapolis.com/products/sharepointlistgadget.aspx)

when i click on authentication to connect to INtranet site, which is secured with SSL, it just hangs the whole PC.

Or if you know anyother way, please mention :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't possible in our Scenario, So I stopped working on this project.

Cheers